# How do I set collation_connection in Django?

Tags: mysql, django, collation

I put this in `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
            'init_command': 'set collation_connection=utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        },
    },
}
```

Then I used the shell to check that it worked:

```
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("show variables like 'collation_connection'")
>>> print cursor.fetchall()
((u'collation_connection', u'utf8mb4_general_ci'),)
```

Unfortunately, what I've learned from inspecting my query log is that `MySQLdb` does this when it connects:

```
set collation_connection='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
SET NAMES utf8mb4
```

That's right.  It executes `set names` after my init command.  This sets the collation back to the default.

Omitting the `'charset'` option doesn't help.  If I do, it will call `set names utf8` instead, which is even worse.  I tried making the `set names` command part of my `'init_command'` in case it wouldn't clobber my collation if there was nothing to change, but no, it still clobbers it.

I can't fork the Python library `MySQLdb` because I'm running my app on Google App Engine and `MySQLdb` is part of App Engine.

Comment: Oh, the list of how "3rd party software gets in the way" grows!

Comment: Please provide a situation where the wrong value for `collation_connection` causes you trouble.

Comment: `collation_connection` only matters in operations that don't touch database columns.  However, it's annoying that there would be an inconsistency there.  I like to remove weird edge cases if possible.  The collation affects a wide variety of things, such as the behavior of any string comparison including equality (=) and the sorting order.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to accomplish this by monkey-patching Django:

```
from django.db.backends.mysql import base
old_get_new_connection = base.DatabaseWrapper.get_new_connection
def get_new_connection(self, conn_params):
  conn = old_get_new_connection(self, conn_params)
  conn.query("set names 'utf8mb4' collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci'")
  return conn

base.DatabaseWrapper.get_new_connection = get_new_connection
```

Btw, this patch was necessary to even use the `utf8mb4` character set on App Engine because they are using an old version of MySQL Connector C which doesn't support that character set.  Without this character set, your app will crash if you attempt to insert any four-byte UTF8 characters, and any existing ones in the database will show up as question marks.

Answer (score -1):

I need to set default Collation for MySQL tables with Django 3.*, I'm using mysqlclient, my settings are:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': get_env_val('MYSQL_DB_NAME'),
    'USER': get_env_val('MYSQL_DB_USER'),
    'PASSWORD': get_env_val('MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'),
    'HOST': get_env_val('MYSQL_DB_HOST'),
    'PORT': get_env_val('MYSQL_DB_PORT'),
    'OPTIONS': {
        'charset': 'utf8mb4',
            }
         }
    }
```